# How does GCC align struct in x64?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, memory-alignment

**TL;DR**

When aligning the stack to multiple of 16 bytes, why are the paddings at the higher address for struct while at the lower address for primitive types?

**More details**

First of all, my machine follows System V AMD64 ABI, and I understand that the stack is aligned to 16 bytes. But when I try to understand how structs are stored on the stack, I found some interesting behavior of GCC that I don't understand.

I have the following program:

```c
struct S {
    long i;
};

void take_struct_addr(struct S *sp);
void take_long_addr(long *l);

void access_member() {
    struct S s;
    take_struct_addr(&s);
}

void access_local() {
    long l;
    take_long_addr(&l);
}
```

I compile it using the following command:

```sh
$ gcc -ansi -pedantic -S -Og access-member.c
```

And I get the following assembly code:

```
    .file   "access-member.c"
    .text
    .globl  access_member
    .type   access_member, @function
access_member:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    movq    %rsp, %rdi # <---------- start address of the struct
    call    take_struct_addr
    addq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   access_member, .-access_member
    .globl  access_local
    .type   access_local, @function
access_local:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi # <---------- start address of the long
    call    take_long_addr
    addq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   access_local, .-access_local
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**So, my question is why are the padding locations different in these two cases?**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It makes no difference. The compiler is free to determine the layout of the locals in the stack frame as long as the alignment requirements are met. It is probably an artifact of compiler internals. You can declare another local variable and see it packed into the same frame.

Comment: A handy way of seeing stack variable layouts is to declare them `volatile` and initialize them.  `volatile long foo = 8;`.  And BTW, your `struct {long};` inherits the alignof() of its most-aligned member, with no extra rules applying, so it's just an 8-byte aligned object that can go anywhere.

Comment: @Jester Yes, if I add more variables, the stack frame alignment is still honored. I'm just curious about the placement of the padding. Is it up to the compiler to decide whether to pad before the local variable or after? Or is there a specification that different compilers will follow?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. However, adding `volatile` doesn't affect the padding placement. Is it totally up to the compiler to decide where to put the padding when satisfying the alignment? Or is there a specification that different compilers will follow?

Comment: That's not what I said.  I said you can compile with optimization enabled and look at a function that contains `volatile struct S s = {1};` and `volatile long l = 2;` to see where the compiler puts them.  Instead of having to disable optimization and / or call `take_struct_addr`.  Of course `alignof(S) = 8` still.

Comment: The specifications usually only deal with interoperability. The layout of a single stack frame normally only concerns the current function (and maybe stuff like exception handlers, stack unwinding).

Comment: @Jester That makes sense. Thanks!